# Sql Server : How to query list of subscriptions and Articles (for a given publication) from Publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

In Sql Server 2014, how to query a list of Subscriptions & its articles for a given Publication **from Publisher**? (transactional replication)

Yes, there are easier ways to query from **Distributor** but I need a query from Publisher side.

Remote Distributor model (if it helps)

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

To get subscription list from a publisher database, you can run below tsql :

```
use publisherDB;
select  
db_name() PublisherDB 
, sp.name as PublisherName 
, sa.name as TableName 
, UPPER(srv.srvname) as SubscriberServerName 
from dbo.syspublications sp  
join dbo.sysarticles sa on sp.pubid = sa.pubid 
join dbo.syssubscriptions s on sa.artid = s.artid 
join master.dbo.sysservers srv on s.srvid = srv.srvid
```

Incase if someone needs for merge replication :

```
use publisherDB
go
select distinct 
    sa.name as articlename,
    sp.publisher as publisherserver,
    sp.publisher_db as publisherdb,
    sp.name as publicationname
    ,ss.subscriber_server as subscriberservername 
from dbo.sysmergearticles sa
join dbo.sysmergepublications sp on sa.pubid = sp.pubid
join dbo.sysmergesubscriptions ss on ss.pubid = sa.pubid
order by subscriberservername
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding listing the subscribers of a publication:**

I had to modify [the query provided by Kin Shah](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/231587/22336) as sometimes I have 2 subscriptions to the same subscriber server and that query was not catching that.

the new script is:

```
use publisher_DB
go

SELECT DISTINCT 
       PublisherDB,
       PublisherName,
       SubscriberServerName,
       SubscriberDBName
       FROM (
                select  
                db_name() PublisherDB 
                , sp.name as PublisherName 
                , sa.name as TableName 
                , UPPER(srv.srvname) as SubscriberServerName 
                , s.dest_db as SubscriberDBName
                from dbo.syspublications sp  
                join dbo.sysarticles sa on sp.pubid = sa.pubid 
                join dbo.syssubscriptions s on sa.artid = s.artid 
                join master.dbo.sysservers srv on s.srvid = srv.srvid 
             ) R
```

[image]

For checking out the list of subscribers of a publication, from the publisher server\database
you can run this script:

```
exec sp_helpsubscription @publication='My_publication'
```

and as this particular publication has 2 subscriptions, you get something like this:

[image]

see you have `sub1` and `sub2`.

---

**Alternatively using powershell:**

from the powershell ide

[image]

#the script below will create the table called `PublicationDatabasesubscriptions`
#in the database called `DBA`, server `DEVELOPMENT_server`

```
invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance "DEVELOPMENT_server" -database "db_publication" -query sp_helpsubscription -OutputAs DataTables |          
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "DEVELOPMENT_server" -DatabaseName DBA -SchemaName dbo -TableName PublicationDatabasesubscriptions -Force
```

After that in SSMS just query that table and you will get the following:

*on server `DEVELOPMENT_server`*

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [subscriber]
      ,[publication]
      ,[article]
      ,[destination database]
      ,[subscription status]
      ,[synchronization type]
      ,[subscription type]
      ,[full subscription]
      ,[subscription name]
      ,[update mode]
      ,[distribution job id]
      ,[loopback_detection]
      ,[offload_enabled]
      ,[offload_server]
      ,[dts_package_name]
      ,[dts_package_location]
      ,[subscriber_security_mode]
      ,[subscriber_login]
      ,[subscriber_password]
      ,[job_login]
      ,[job_password]
      ,[distrib_agent_name]
      ,[subscriber_type]
      ,[subscriber_provider]
      ,[subscriber_datasource]
      ,[subscriber_providerstring]
      ,[subscriber_location]
      ,[subscriber_catalog]
  FROM [DBA].[dbo].[PublicationDatabasesubscriptions]
```

that query gives you this:

[image]

---

### **What if you want to save sp_helpsubscription into a table?**

That can also be done following the stept below.

*on server `DEVELOPMENT_server`*

```
use my_pub_db --my publication database

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Radhe') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Radhe

CREATE TABLE #Radhe ( 
[subscriber]                 NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[publication]                NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[article]                    NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[destination database]       NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscription status]        INT                                         NULL,
[synchronization type]       TINYINT                                     NULL,
[subscription type]          INT                                         NULL,
[full subscription]          BIT                                         NULL,
[subscription name]          NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[update mode]                INT                                         NULL,
[distribution job id]        VARBINARY(max)                              NULL,
[loopback_detection]         BIT                                         NULL,
[offload_enabled]            BIT                                         NULL,
[offload_server]             NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[dts_package_name]           NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[dts_package_location]       INT                                         NULL,
[subscriber_security_mode]   SMALLINT                                    NULL,
[subscriber_login]           NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscriber_password]        NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[job_login]                  NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[job_password]               NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[distrib_agent_name]         NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscriber_type]            TINYINT                                     NULL,
[subscriber_provider]        NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscriber_datasource]      NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscriber_providerstring]  NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscriber_location]        NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL,
[subscriber_catalog]         NVARCHAR(max)                               NULL)


insert into #Radhe
exec my_pub_db.dbo.sp_helpsubscription @publication='JUNOCore_Repl_Pub'


select * from #Radhe
where article = 'applicantSkill'
```

this gives me the following error message but still inserts the records in the table.

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_helpsubscription,
> Line 537 [Batch Start Line 36] An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be
> nested.

[image]

and the result of the query above is:

[image]

---

**Regarding the listing of the articles of a publication:**

These are some of the scripts that I use for listing the articles of a publication.
These are queries from the publisher server, publisher database as requested by OP.

```
    --SET NOEXEC ON 
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    SET NOCOUNT ON
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--the server is my server
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print @@servername

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--the database is: my_publication_db
-- this database is published and has 2 subscriptions
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print db_name()

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- script - Quick way to determine the articles - and their columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE my_publication_db
GO

SELECT 
   syspublications.name AS "Publication", 
   sysarticles.name AS "Article", 
   STUFF( 
       ( 
           SELECT ', ' + syscolumns.name AS [text()] 
           FROM sysarticlecolumns WITH (NOLOCK) 
               INNER JOIN syscolumns WITH (NOLOCK) ON sysarticlecolumns.colid = syscolumns.colorder 
           WHERE sysarticlecolumns.artid = sysarticles.artid 
               AND sysarticles.objid = syscolumns.id 
           ORDER BY syscolumns.colorder 
           FOR XML PATH('') 
       ), 1, 2, '' 
   ) AS "Columns" FROM syspublications WITH (NOLOCK) 
   INNER JOIN sysarticles WITH (NOLOCK) ON syspublications.pubid = sysarticles.pubid 
ORDER BY syspublications.name, sysarticles.name
```

[image]

```
exec sp_helppublication

exec sp_helparticle @publication='my_publication'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Find source and destination tables - with schema
--marcello miorelli
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SELECT art.artid,
         table_name      = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(art.OBJID) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(art.OBJID),
         dest_table_name = art.dest_owner + N'.' + art.dest_table,      
         sync_table_name = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(art.sync_objid) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(art.sync_objid),
 
         art.[del_cmd],
         art.[upd_cmd],
         art.[ins_cmd],
         art.[filter],
         art.[filter_clause],
         [fire triggers when running snapshot]=case when art.fire_triggers_on_snapshot = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No ' end,
         art.[schema_option]

  FROM syspublications pub
  INNER JOIN sysarticles art
          ON art.pubid = pub.pubid
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was the approach I ended up doing. Thanks for the detailed response. This will be helpful for many people.

Comment: thank you @ToC and I just added another query, because in one of my environments I have 2 subscriptions to the same subscriber server, and I wanted a clear list of that.

Answer (score 0):

Found this sys proc,  not sure if it is correct.

`sp_helpsubscription`

Any ideas for better solution?

Thanks,

Comment: `EXEC sp_helpsubscription  @publication = 'Publication', @article = 'Table', @found = @DoesSubscriptionAlreadyExist OUTPUT
SELECT @DoesSubscriptionAlreadyExist`